# How can I create an HTML mail that loads an image from an external server?

Tags: email, thunderbird, html

I want to create an HTML mail that embeds an image. However, I don't want Thunderbird to inline this image in any way. Rather, the image, located on a web server, should be loaded from this web server when the mail is opened.

Is it possible using popular mail clients (I am on Mac) or do I need to use mail service providers such as Litmus or Acid Email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Thunderbird, insert the image into your message using the *Insert* -> *Image...* command.

In the *Image Location:* field enter the URL to the image you want to insert.

Ensure the *Attach this image to the message* checkbox is **not** checked.